# "Add import ..." and "Add all unambiguous imports" quick fixes are missing in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, import, ide, settings, webstorm

Today I found out that these two quick fixes are missing for me. It's very inconvenient. How can I revert back to normal?

[image]

Comment: most probably the IDE was unable to resolve the corresponding module. As far as I can see, there are no imports suggestions from the Typescript language service as well, so it must be a problem with either the way the module is declared or with the project configuration

Comment: Interesting! It worked before, and today I'm facing these problems. What could go wrong? :)

Comment: no idea:( any changes in code/configuration?